# Fetch only items 'x' items from an api instead of all and load more content when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rest

I'm making a simple GK app that shows user information about countries and makes use of restcountries API.
I make request a to "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all" which returns data about all countries.
But how do I make a request for just certain countries like the first 10 or 15 countries from the API , display it on the webpage or once all the content is returned, display only first 10 or 15 countries, and once the user scrolls down more content from the API is loaded?

rest countries API link : https://restcountries.eu/#rest-countries

```
    HTML CODE:
       <div class="list-of-countries">
          //Countries are displayed in this block
       </div>

    JS CODE:
        function displayCountries(countries) {
  countries.forEach((country) => {
    console.log(country);
    let countryCard = $(`<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
   <img src="${country.flag}" class="card-img-top" alt="${country.name} Flag">
   <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">${country.name} </h5>
       <p class="card-text">Population : ${country.population}</p>
       <p class="card-text">Region : ${country.region}</p>
       <p class="card-text">Capital : ${country.capital}</p>
   </div>
  </div>`);

    $(".list-of-countries").append(countryCard);
  });
}
window.onload = fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((response) => {
    displayCountries(response);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: If API does not provide such functionality, you can't do anything about it (unless pagination in front-end only). Maybe all endpoints are just static pages that you directly get

Comment: ohh okay...but like once all data is returned, could I perform a javascript function to  show  only certain items

Comment: Yes, you can do later whatever you want with it.